# Virtual Box Security

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, kubuntu

I installed vb in my kubuntu, but I'm a little concern about viruses or other stuff infiltrating on my linux through the OS installed, such as Windos 7. So, how can I avoid any information coming out of the virtual OS?

Thank you

Comment: A virus targeted to infect a Windows machine cannot infect a Kubuntu host.  If your guest vm is download a virus, targeted to escape a virtual machine, you have an additional problem.  **You have bad usage habits.**

Answer (score 1):

By default the Guest runs using a NAT network, meaning that it is secured to not let anything get out unless you make it possible.

A virus can always come in the Guest, but it will then be contained inside the guest.

However, for a virus to reach the guest, you will need to do something that will get the virus in there, such as run malicious code. (like run a wrong exe or visit a wrong site) If you don't do that, the virus can't get there in the first place.

And lastly, a worth mention: Linux uses different kind of executables than Windows does. This means that even if a windows machine was infected with a virus, it could not infect a linux install because the code is different. It can however alter documents, that resides on the linux install, and for that you still need to make sure the security is tight enough (such as setting it to NAT as it is by default)